# C- printf hex values giving unexpected output

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to learn some of the basics of C and I have been reading nonstop about gets/fgets/puts/scanf and can't seem to get this right...

My code is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFF 256

void main()
{

char s[BUFF];
fgets(s, BUFF, stdin);
s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
printf("%x %s %d", s, s, strlen(s));
}
```

I'm trying to get the hex format of the variable s to print, my input is AAAA and the output I want is 41414141 AAAA 4, the output I'm getting is 12fe80 AAAA 4.

I thought I needed to cast s (as a u int) for the hex interpretation, but that didn't work either.

I would really appreciate an explanation on this as well as help, I'm really trying to learn this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main()
```

This isn't your problem, but the correct definition is

```
int main(void)
```

`void main()` is useful mostly as a tool to detect C textbooks written by incompetent authors.

```
printf("%x %s %d", s, s, strlen(s));
```

This has undefined behavior:

- `"%x"` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`; you're giving it a `char*` (the array expression `s` is converted to a pointer to its first element).
- `%d` requires an argument of type `int`; you're giving it a `size_t`. Either convert it to `int`, or use `%zu`.

If you want to print a hexadecimal representation of the contents of the string `s`, there's no direct way to do that. You'll just have to loop over the characters contained in `s` and print the value of each one in hexadecimal. (You should cast each `char` value to `unsigned int` so it works properly with the `"%02x"` format.)

Answer (score 2):

`%x` works on numbers. You're passing in a pointer to a string. So in this case `printf()` is interpreting the pointer (memory address) as a number and printing that address in hex format. Sounds like you just want to print the ASCII values, in hex, of each character in the input:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    printf("%02x", (unsigned) s[i]);
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're right, I didn't think through the `- 1`. Will remove that comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The hex value you are printing is the address of the string, not the contents (since `s` is a `char*`).

To see the full contents of the string as hex bytes, you will have to do something like this:

```
int n = strlen(s);
for(int ii=0; ii<n; ii++) printf("%02x", (unsigned int) s[ii]);
```

Comment: Your first `printf` has undefined behavior. How do you know that the first `sizeof (int)` bytes of `s` are correctly aligned? What about byte order? `%x` requires an `unsigned int`, not an `int`. `%d` requires an `int`; `strlen()` returns a `size_t` result. (Yes, I downvoted.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I appreciate your inputs. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm saying no compiler, regardless of how *modern* it is, is *required* to cope with badly aligned pointers. (x86 happens to handle misaligned addresses in hardware; other platforms require strict alignment). The point is that your first `printf` has undefined behavior, and IMHO is poor style as well. And I see you deleted it from your answer as I was writing this, so I'll withdraw the downvote. But you're computing `strlen(s)` on every iteration of the loop, which is inefficient.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I guess I have never used a platform that had trouble with misaligned pointers, but I see your point. And I've eliminated the "gross inefficiency" in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFF 256

int main()
{
  int i = 0;              /* a counter */
  char s[BUFF];
  fgets(s, BUFF, stdin);
  s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
  while (i < strlen(s)) { /* to get the character(s) in s */
    printf("%x", s[i]);   /* as hex */
    i++;
  }
  printf(" %s %d\n", s, strlen(s)); /* as before */
}
$ gcc hello.c -o hello && echo "AAAA" | ./hello
41414141 AAAA 4
```

Answer (score 0):

print all the array index one by one.

```
printf("%x ", *s);
printf("%x ", *(s+1));
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {

    char a[]="AAAA";
    printf("%x%x%x%x %s %d", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a, (int)strlen(a));
}
```